# Problem linking an Assembly (AT&T) file with C program using GCC

Tags: c, macos, assembly, linker-errors, abi

I have my C program in 'main.c' and a function called list_equal() in 'list_equal.c'.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main.h"

int list_equal(const node_t *l1, const node_t *l2) {
    while (l1!=NULL && l2!=NULL) {
        if (l1->elem != l2->elem) return 0;
        l1 = l1->next;
        l2 = l2->next;
    }
    return l1==NULL && l2==NULL;
}
```

When I compile my program using:

```
$ gcc -m32 main.c list_equal.c -o main
```

everything worked fine and I was able to run my program './main'.

Then I translated my function in assembly code using AT&T syntax and named it "list_equal.s". Here's the code.

```
.globl list_equal

list_equal:

movl 4(%esp),%eax
movl 8(%esp),%ecx

L:

testl %eax,%eax
jz E
testl %ecx,%ecx
jz E
movw (%ecx),%dx
cmpw %dx,(%eax)
je F
movl $0,%eax
ret

E:

testl %eax,%eax
setz %al
testl %ecx,%ecx
setz %ah
andb %ah,%al
movsbl %al,%eax
ret

F:

movl 4(%eax),%eax
movl 4(%ecx),%ecx
jmp L
```

But when I try to compile my program again, this time using the assembly 'list_equal.s', with the command:

```
$gcc -m32 main.c list_equal.s -o main
```

I get this error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_list_equal", referenced from:
      _test in main-bbda7f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thank you in advance.

Informations about my gcc compiler:

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode_9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode_9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: Change `list_equal` to `_list_equal` in "list_equal.s".

Comment: You should add a tag for the OS you're using, since this behavior is specific to it.

Comment: Side note: have a look at gcc/clang optimized output as a starting point.  https://godbolt.org/z/8_ktC1 e.g. notice that `l1==NULL && l2==NULL` in the return path can be implemented with `or l1, l2` / `setz %al`.  (Unfortunately nothing as efficient for checking that they're *both* non-NULL; compilers choose to branch twice instead of creating booleans and ANDing.)

Comment: To use a single branch for the test *inside* the loop, I might go for CMOV:  basically do `tmp = l1 ? l2 : 0` and then test `tmp` for being non-zero.  xor-zero `tmp` to start, then test/cmov into it and `test` it against itself.  `setcc` unfortunately costs extra uops to use safely (xor-zeroing to avoid partial-register slowdowns).  But you were just using 2 branches like compilers do, and that's probably fine.  But lay out the fast path through the loop to have fewer taken branches.  e.g. fall through to the return false block, normally jumping up to the l1=l1->next block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler prepends an underscore character at the function name.

You can see what the compiler generates if you call it like this:

```
gcc -S -m32 list_equal.c -o list_equal.c.s
```

Without `-m32` there is no extra character.

Comment: This is specific to certain backwards systems, typically ones based on a COFF lineage. ELF systems do not do this.

Comment: @R.. Mach-O does it as well.  ELF is the (good) outlier here.

Comment: Yes, I figured it was likely Mach-O based on what's popular these days. I wonder where it inherited this wackiness from. Does it have COFF-related roots?